# Reference to an image on another server in HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I have two servers, 'Localhost' and 'Server1'. I want `page.html` on Localhost to reference a picture on Server1. This is the error I am getting:

```
biggie.jpg:1 GET http://localhost/img/team/biggie.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the script picking the picture

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "http://server1/integration/team.php";
        $.getJSON(url, function(result) { 
            console.log(result);
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                var name = field.name;
                var surname = field.surname;
                var nickname = field.nickname;
                var descritpion = field.descritpion;
                var pic = field.pic;
                $("#teamview").append("<div class='even gradeA'><p align='center' class='item-content'><img src="+pic+" width=100 > <br /> "+name+" "+surname+" - "+nickname+" <br />"+descritpion+"</p></div>");
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code is on a mobile app I am building with PhoneGap for a Hybrid Mobile App! So I have the path for the image stored in a database table. I want to fetch the image to display in a div inside the app.

Comment: Maybe a spelling issue  - like the `descritpion` one?

Comment: Not really. It is spelt that way in database

Comment: http://localhost/img/team/biggie.jpg this url is your localhost it should be server url

Comment: `<img src="http://server1/'+pic+'` - that's the case?

Comment: It looks like the `field.pic` is returned as a relative path to the file on Server1, hence the problem. You need to return an absolute path

Comment: Even when I put full path it adds localhost before that

Comment: you can add that Img in server folder and give that path that will work

Comment: Even when I put for the full path of Server1 it appends localhost before

Comment: what is the value of `pic` coming right now? do `console.log(pic);` and let us know

Comment: Then I am damn sure you have added hard code URL in your code with "localhost" element

Comment: No. No hard coding of any path in code. That code segment is all I have besides the php giving the json.

Comment: var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        var loc = window.location; check this in your code what is the path name and location

Comment: alert(window.location.pathname); gives me the folder in the localhost /XXXXX/

Comment: share your image fullpath.

Comment: The image is in xampp folder server1/integration/team/img/biggie.jpg. So I have stored this image path in the database with the intention of dynamically pulling images from that folder to the app

Comment: 'http://server1/integration/team/img/biggie.jpg' make sure this path Image  should be open while punting this path in browser other wise change server1 with IP address.